# NRPE service not starting in SUSE linux 15 sp 3

Tags: linux, suse, nagios, nrpe

Couldn't start nrpe.service in SUSE linux 15 sp3. I have installed monitoring-plugins-nrpe package but no service shown and when try to start "systemctl start nrpe.service" command then below error shows
"Failed to start nrpe.service: Unit nrpe.service not found"

Comment: I don't have a place to test at the moment, but it seems to me from https://software.opensuse.org/package/nrpe that: "There is no official package available for openSUSE Leap 15.5" and "It could be run by an inetd, or as a standalone daemon". Further, based on https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE:Leap:15.3/nrpe, there's only an nrpe.init file intended for SysV style startup, not systemctl/systemd.